# AngularJS 1 : $http always return status code -1 when request fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

I would like to intercept 500 error and higher.

I get inspired by:

- [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)
- [AngularJs - $http.get request, response with -1 status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377135/angularjs-http-get-request-response-with-1-status-code)
- and other similar questions

this is the `ServiceErrorInterceptor`

```
app.factory('ServerErrorInterceptor',
[ '$q',
  function ($q) {
    return {
      'requestError': function(rejection) {
        console.log( rejection );
         return $q.reject(rejection);
      },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            console.log( rejection );
           return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

which always returns

```
Object { data: null, status: -1, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "", xhrStatus: "error" }
```

while [Network] bowser tab shows clearly `400`, `405`, `500`, `503` ... depending of the case.

How can I get the http error code?

Comment: `-1` usually means that some problem took place, like CORS or timeout. Can you replicate the problem as a plunk or something?

Comment: try to intercept response too ... it helped us to get the HTTP code for errors and you need to use if switch in the callback method

Comment: thanks @estus I finally opted to isolate the server part by a local PHP page which is by setting headers only. And YES setting `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` allows Angular to read the status. Which is not fun when you do not have control on the real server.

Comment: @jabo87 sure I inspected `response` and `request` but that have not been relevant here.

Comment: When you have multidomain setup you should be prepared for this. And if you don't have control over API server headers, you have to resort to CORS proxy. Not specific to Angular but to client-side JS in whole.